# Generate excel report and use it as mail attachment in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I am trying to write a rake task to periodically generate an excel report and use the generated file as an `ActionMailer` attachment.

I currently have a working `transactions#report` action to generate the file as requested by the user, and the approach I was taking was to call this same action inside of the rake task, but I don't know if the excel file is being generated or how can I access it to use it as attachment. I don't know if this is the way to go to generate a template view inside a rake task that I can use later.

This is my rake task code at the moment:

`lib\tasks\informes.rake`

```
namespace :reports do
 desc "Generate daily transaction reports and attach it by email"
 task attach_transactions: :environment do
   session = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)
   session.get "/transactions/report"
 end
end
```

And this is the method in the transactions controller that generates the excel file.

```
def report
  @transactions = Transaction.all
  respond_to do |format| 
    format.xlsx
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Informe_Suministro.xlsx"'
  end
end
```

Comment: i think you need to save files on server and then attach files to email to send.

Comment: you dont need to call your own controller to get code triggered ;)

Comment: Can you please extend your answer? How can I render the view template inside the rake task order to save it?